# d3 Bounded Force layout with Zoom and Pan

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, pan, force-layout

I am working on a bounded force layout with a zoom and pan (D3.js). The main problem is that I'm not able to adequately customize the zoom behavior.

My graph contains several movable elements, that a user can move through the svg-element. So I implemented a bounding box to prevent the user to push outside the graph.

I configured my tick function in this way:

```
function tick() {
  // r: radius of a circle ; w: width ; h: height
  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(r, Math.min(w - r, d.x)); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(r, Math.min(h - r, d.y)); });
```

(http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492)

It worked well until I decided to add a zoom and pan feature.

I limited the scale of my zoom : zoom.scaleExtent([0.5, 2]);

So I thought that when I zoom out, my drawing will be shrink by 50%, so doing something like that will be enough:

```
d.x = Math.max(r, Math.min((w*0.5+W) - r, d.x));
d.y = Math.max(r, Math.min((h*0.5+h) - r, d.y));
```

**But it appears that my graph is not correctly delimited, is there something wrong with these formulas?**

Also, the entire graph is draggable when the user clicks on a blank area thanks to:

```
vis.append('svg:rect')
.attr('width', w)
.attr('height', h)
.attr('fill', 'white');
```

([Is there a way to zoom into a D3 force layout graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871425/is-there-a-way-to-zoom-into-a-graph-layout-done-using-d3))

**However this rectangle is draggable indefinitely, and it's not convenient for a bounded force layout. How can I delimit it?**