# How do I use d3's brushing/dragging/zoom behaviors in a meteor project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, meteor

I'm trying to build a souped-up force-layout graph based on [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/benzguo/4370043) using Meteor.js and D3.js.

Here's the problem:

**In this project and in other projects involving d3 mouse-move events within a meteor framework, incorporating the mouse-event functionality causes the app to break.**
By break, I mean either crash, throw errors on mouse-drags etc., or otherwise act unruly.

Two questions really:

- **Why is this happening?**  What is causing this frustrating behavior?  Is this problem fixable, or do I need to try building this app using a different framework?
- **How can I prevent this behavior** or get around it?  I've tried building the same app using divs for graph nodes and using jquery's draggable feature to drag whem, which works great, but it's kindof a hack, because I still can't use D3 features like brushing and zooming.

[Here is a link to a very-simple version of the force-layout editor being incorporated in a meteor environment](https://github.com/goodwordalchemy/experinode/tree/master/simple_copy).  This program allows the user to drag the node, but all other functionality is lost.  Dragging the single node that appears throws the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`

The user is unable to select a node, draw new nodes, or do anything else that the app is programmed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ["preventing default"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953106/why-does-d3-js-v3-break-my-force-graph-when-implementing-zooming-when-v2-doesnt) was the culprit...I just got my graph to select nodes and draw connections.

[Here was the key to the drag line not working](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Events).  It turns out that `d3.svg.mouse(container)` is deprecated.  You're supposed to use `d3.mouse` now.

This is really great news, because it means d3 and meteor are more compatible than I thought.