# d3 force layout zoom and pan conflict with node drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js, force-layout

My force layout graph is construct by d3.js. I want add zoom and pan to my force graph. 
I have access to relevant information,and the zoom and pan works.But it bring new problem when I try to drag the node to somewhere only make the whole graph panning,the before node drag function is does not works. The approach I taken is  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871425/is-there-a-way-to-zoom-into-a-d3-force-layout-graph)

I find the key point is the

```
.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw))
.append('svg:g');
```

but when I delete `.append('svg:g');` the zoom and pan not working again. So how can I keep these functions(zoom and pan,node drag) at the same time.

I need the effort like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lazybios/GpYSW/),I follow this method to my own project but it does not works,I don't konw if I missing something.

Comment: Your jsfiddle works fine for me.

Comment: Define "does not work", it works for me. What browser is affected? Are you using the latest D3.js library?

Comment: @Lekensteyn Yes,it works fine ,but that not mine.I find it in the other stackoverflow anwser [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871425/is-there-a-way-to-zoom-into-a-d3-force-layout-graph) But in my project it does not work. I want to know Why? and what decide the drag function?

Comment: @lazybios Could you provide a minimal example that exposes the problem? Be aware that in d3.js, `foo.call(bar)` is equivalent to `bar(foo)` and that drag and zoom/pan cannot be applied to the same element. You probably want to make just the nodes draggable while allowing pan/zoom on the svg element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work only on older versions. E.g. http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js works but 
dragging does not work properly on http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js.